# Same Location updates in the background even though I have moved Significantly

Tags: android, geolocation, android-service, android-location

I have a service which request network location updates in it's onCreateMethod. I have used LocationListener to receive new locations, status of the providers and the statusChange in the provider.

While the device is in low power state(phone screen is off), I get the same location fix that was with the network provider when the phone screen was active(screen is on).

```
public class LocationRegisterService extends Service implements LocationListener{

private String TAG = LocationRegisterService.class.getName();

private LocationManager lm;

public void onCreate()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"Entering LocationRegisterService::onCreate()");
    //Register for network location updates
    lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Log.i(TAG,"Regsitering for Network Location Updates");
    Log.i(TAG,"minTime = 0,minDistance = 0");
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            Log.d(TAG,"Exiting LocationRegisterSerivce::onCreate()");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d(TAG,"Entering LocationRegisterService::onStartCommand()");
    Log.d(TAG,"Exiting LocationRegisterService::onStartCommand()");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG,"Entering LocationRegisterService::onDestroy()");
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    Log.d(TAG,"Exiting LocationRegisterService::onDestroy()");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Helpers.logScreenStatus(this);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    String location_timestamp = formatTime(location.getTime());
    String log = latitude + "," + longitude +","+accuracy+","+location_timestamp;
    Log.i(TAG,log);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    String log = "Network Provider Disabled";
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    String log = "Network Provider Enabled";
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    String log = "";
    switch(status){
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            log = "Network Available";
            break;
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            log = "Network Out Of Service";
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            log = "Network Temporarily Unavailable";
            break;
    }
    setServiceWakeUpTime();
    stopSelf();
}

private void setServiceWakeUpTime()
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long wakeAt = System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wakeAt , operation);
    FileLogger.log(this, "Service will wake up after one minute");
}

private String formatTime(long epoch)
{
    Date date = new Date(epoch);
    String pattern = "y/M/d H:m:s.S";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

}
```

I started this service from an activity and travelled almost 50KM with the device screen off. I am attaching the logs of the travel.

```
2013/3/21 0:29:58.743  Entering Broadcast Receiver
2013/3/21 0:29:58.756  Screen is off
2013/3/21 0:29:58.778  Exiting Broadcast Receiver
2013/3/21 0:29:58.783  Registering for network location updates
2013/3/21 0:30:53.571  Screen is off
2013/3/21 0:30:53.587  13.07383585,80.22151335000001,50.0,2013/3/21 0:30:8.551
2013/3/21 0:30:53.593  Screen is off
2013/3/21 0:30:53.595  Network Temporarily Unavailable
2013/3/21 0:30:53.613  Service will wake up after one minute
2013/3/21 0:30:53.619  UnRegistering listener for location updates
2013/3/21 0:31:53.676  Entering Broadcast Receiver
2013/3/21 0:31:53.689  Screen is off
2013/3/21 0:31:53.710  Exiting Broadcast Receiver
2013/3/21 0:31:58.516  Registering for network location updates
2013/3/21 0:32:17.583  Screen is off
2013/3/21 0:32:17.594  13.07383585,80.22151335000001,50.0,2013/3/21 0:32:3.544
```

The same log is repeated for almost an hour. This code was run in HTC Explorer with Android 2.3.3. Does anybody have answer for this behavior ?

Comment: I will try using partial wake lock and share my results.

Comment: What happens if you comment `setServiceWakeUpTime();` and `stopSelf();` in `onStatusChange()`? According to the logs, your provider just moved to Temporary Unavailable state. It can recover from it in a few seconds. See if it gives you correct updates once it recovers.

Comment: @AshishGupta The problem above I have mentioned occurs only in HTC. Once the device is inactive for more than 15 minutes, it turns off wifi and any active mobile data connections. So, it is returning same locations even though I have moved significantly.

Comment: @DavidOlsson Using WakeLocks doesn't make any difference here. I tried the above code by exclusively receiving the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, but the same results(Same location updates in the background even though I have moved significantly).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of getting same location updates is happening only in HTC mobile phones. I don't know whether this occurs on all HTC Android Phones. But it occurs for sure on my HTC Explorer.

The reason for getting same location updates in the background is, once the phone is inactive for more than 15 minutes, HTC disable add active Internet connections (WIFI or Mobile data connection). To cross check this, I wrote the following code.

- An activity which schedule an AlarmReceiver to be called after one minute.
- The Alarm Receiver checks whether there are any connection through which an internet connection can be established.
- The Alarm Receiver registers an alarm to call itself after one minute

I made the code to run through out the night.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Entering Broadcast Receiver onReceive");
    FileLogger.log(context, "Entering Broadcast Receiver");
    logActiveNetworkInfo(context);
    setAlarm(context);
    FileLogger.log(context, "Exiting Broadcast Receiver");
    Log.i(TAG, "Exiting Broadcast Receiver onReceive");
}

private void logActiveNetworkInfo(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo == null)
    {
        FileLogger.log(context, "No network connectivity");
        return;
    }
    String networkTypeName = networkInfo.getTypeName();
    boolean isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();
    String log = "";
    if(isConnected == true)
    {
        log = "Internet available through " + networkTypeName;
    }
    else
        log = "Internet not available through "+ networkTypeName;
    FileLogger.log(context, log);
    Log.i(TAG,log);
    return;
}

private void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long wakeUpAt = System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                                                         0,
                                                         intent,
                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, wakeUpAt , operation);
    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm set to ring after "+wakeUpAt + " milliseconds");
}
```

}

**So app developers be careful, if you want to make HTTP call in the background in a HTC phone, it will fail if the phone is inactive for more than fifteen minutes.**

This issue has been reported [HTC Deep Sleep](http://www.androidpolice.com/tags/fix-smartsync/)

Comment: It's to do with the `SmartSync` feature in HTC devices.